# Type error: Page "" has an invalid "default" export: Type "" is not valid

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

Please not, I'm new to react and NextJS.

I'm working on a small project using nextjs 13, trying to display products currently stored in json file (later will move to DB). Application is running correctly, however when building it fails on linting.

Error:
`Type error: Page "src/app/shop/page.tsx" has an invalid "default" export: Type "Products" is not valid.`

I'm importing interface from child component, where I'm displaying the product:

`import ProductTile, { Product } from "./product-tile";`

Then I'm creating interface for page:

```
interface Products {
  products: Product[];
}
```

Products are used as props on page:

```
export default function Page({ products }: Products) {}
```

---

Here is whole product interface used in **product-tile**:

```
export interface Product {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  type: string;
  profile: string[];
  description: string;
  price: Price[];
  img: string;
  allergens: Allergens;
}

export interface Price {
  size: string;
  price: number;
  dimension: Dimension[];
}

export interface Dimension {
  width: number;
  depth: number;
}

export interface Allergens {
  nuts: boolean;
  gluten: boolean;
  lactose: boolean;
  eggs: boolean;
  milk: boolean;
}
```

Any idea why it's not happy with this code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to the official doc https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/page

`pages.js/tsx` can only has the `props` of `params` and `searchParams`, which mean only these 2 types are welcomed in this kind of file.

What you might want to do is to have the `page.tsx` render the component you want inside the `Page` component you have there, then pass the `props` and the corresponding type in it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the default export of `page.{tsx,jsx}`, `layout.{tsx,jsx}`, `template.{tsx,jsx}`, `loading.{tsx,jsx}`, `error.{tsx,jsx}`, `not-found.{tsx,jsx}`, and `default.{tsx,jsx}` must be a react component.
and `function ({products}) {}` is not a valid react component since it doesn't return a JSX.

You have to return any valid `ReactNode` like JSX, string, number, null, or undefined.

The correct code should be:

```js
export function Page({products}: Props) {
  return <h1>Hello world!</h1>
  // return <></>
  // return null
  // return "Hello world!"
}
```